# CKEditor 4 inline editing save button plugin

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, ckeditor

[image]

i have just created a plugin ajax save. i have looked around the documentation instead its getting me confused to implement it.
how do i make the button work when click and save the content via ajax php? at the moment i cant get the content.

**folder : /plugins/ajaxsave/plugin.js**

```
var saveCmd = {
    modes : { wysiwyg:1 },
    exec : function( editor ) {
        **var $content = editor.instances.editor1.getData(); ?????**
        var $data = {'keyId': 1, 'token': TOKEN, 'content': $content};

        $.ajax({
            type: 'post',
            url: '../../script/php/file.php',
            data: $data,
            dataType: 'json',
            cache: false,
            success: function(data) {

                    alert( 'OK' );

            },
            error: function(data){
                alert('fatal error');
            }
        });
       CKEDITOR.instances.editor1.destroy();
   }

}
CKEDITOR.plugins.add('ajaxsave',  {    

    init:function(editor) {

        var pluginName = 'ajaxsave';
        var command = editor.addCommand(pluginName,saveCmd);
        command.modes = {wysiwyg:1 };   

        editor.ui.addButton('ajaxsave', {
            label: 'Save text',
            command: pluginName,
            toolbar: 'undo,1',
            icon: this.path+'save.png'
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: What is the problem? Does it give you an error? Does it not save? Please walk us through the problem.

Comment: @Trufa it does not recognise the editable content. How do i get the content and passing it through ajax.

Answer (score 3):

```
**var $content = editor.instances.editor1.getData(); ?????**
```

Should be:

```
var $content = editor.getData();
```

`editor` there is an argument of init method of your plugin. This method is called for each editor instance.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :-

```
  var ckvalue = CKEDITOR.instances['editor1'].getData(); // editor1 is id of the ckeditor textarea


   //or

   $('#editor1').ckeditor(function( textarea ){
    $(textarea).val();
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look to my question-answer here

[How to add an ajax save button with loading gif to CKeditor 4.2.1. [Working Sample Plugin]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18956257/how-to-add-an-ajax-save-button-with-loading-gif-to-ckeditor-4-2-1-sample-plugi)

there is a download link in the answer to a working save button plugin.